# kernel TCP/IP implementation - about accept queue

Tags: networking, kernel, linux-kernel, tcp, source-code

I'm recently learning the TCP/IP implementation in linux kernel(version 4.4), and got really confused about the accept queue. I know there is a queue in `struct inet_connection_sock` which is called a **accept queue**:

```
struct inet_connection_sock {
    ...
    /* @icsk_accept_queue:     FIFO of established children */
    struct request_sock_queue icsk_accept_queue;
    ...
}
```

and there is a `qlen` member in it, I think it is used to indicate the length of the queue.

When a LISTEN socket receives a SYN packet, in function [`tcp_conn_request`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6298), [`inet_csk_reqsk_queue_hash_add`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/include/net/inet_connection_sock.h#L282) is called to put the newly created NEW_SYN_RECV sock into ehash table (not `icsk_accept_queue`). But in `inet_csk_reqsk_queue_hash_add`, [`inet_csk_reqsk_queue_added`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/include/net/inet_connection_sock.h#L282) is called to increment `icsk_accept_queue.len`. My question is why increment `qlen` since nothing is inserted to `icsk_accept_queue`?

What's more, [`tcp_conn_request`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L6291) also called [`inet_csk_reqsk_queue_add`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c#L793) to add a fast open sock(if enabled) to `icsk_accept_queue`, but this function ended up incrementing `sk.sk_ack_backlog` (by calling [`sk_acceptq_added`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.131/source/include/net/sock.h#L791)) instead of `icsk_accept_queue.qlen`... What am I missing?